# R-module structure from R-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading through Dummit and Foote and one of the examples I do not understand. The example is from 10.1, page 343.

(3) If $A$ is an $R$-algebra then the $R$-module structure of $A$ depends only on the subring $f(R)$ contained in the center of $A$.

How do you obtain an $R$-module structure from this?

Answer (score 0):

An $R$ algebra is by definition a morphism of rings $f : R \to A$, where $A$ is a ring with $1$. For $a\in A$ and $r\in R$ one notes $ra = f(r)a$ and $ar = a f(r)$. Now this defines a structure of left and respectively right $R$-module on $A$. (Just try it.) Finally, $f(R)$ is in the center of $A$ *if* $R$ is a commutative ring, because then $bb' = b'b$ for all $b,b'\in f(R)$, as $R$ is commutative and $f$ a morphism of rings. Assuming directely that $f(R)$ is in the center does give you *directly* $bb' = b'b$ for all $b,b'\in f(R)$.

Comment: The fact that $f(R)$ is in the center of $A$ is included in the definition of $R$-algebra. It surely doesn't follow from your argument.

Comment: Never wrote it does. But I hope that it will put the OP in a mood to understand why being in the center is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am also reading exactly here. I think that the R-module of A here specifically refers to the module defined in the last paragraph of Page 342, i.e. r·a=a·r=f(r)·a. Please let me know if there is a better explanation. Many thanks in advance!